# The called function should be payable error in withdraw function

Tags: solidity

I have such function to transfer tokens from contract and i get error where shoudl i add payable and i dont really understand if withdraw will withdraw ethers or tokens?

```
function withdrawBalances() public nonReentrant {
            uint share = _Balances[msg.sender];
           _Balances[msg.sender] = 0;
            msg.sender.transfer(share);
        }
```

.withdrawBalances errored: VM error: revert. revert The transaction has been reverted to the initial state. Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance. Debug the transaction to get more information.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when you try to send some Ether when calling a function that isn't payable. Set Ether value to 0 to avoid this. You can also allow a function to accept Ether by using the payable keyword.

```
function withdrawBalances() public payable {
     ...
}
```

Comment: how can i set ether to 0? in this function?

Comment: It should be 0 by default. How are you currently sending the transaction?

Comment: 'uint share = _WithdrawBalances[msg.sender];
       _WithdrawBalances[msg.sender] = 0;
        msg.sender.transfer(share);'

Comment: I dont understand one thing difference between ehters withdraw from contract and tokens. How can i withdraw ethers and how tokens?

Comment: Let me rephrase my previous question. How are you calling the withdrawBalances function? That's where the problem is. Using transfer will transfer ETH. To transfer tokens you need to get a contract instance e.g. 'ERC20 instance = ERC20(<address of token>)' and call the contract's functions (transferFrom or transfer).

Comment: Also inside contract who owns tokens itself ?Do i need to create instance inside contract? - i as a contract creator will send tokens to the contract address so will gather some tokens inside contract itself and from this contract i want users to be able to withdraw them not from any other outside contract.

Comment: You have to reference the existing token contract. Try taking a look at this guide: https://ethereumdev.io/transfers-and-approval-or-erc20-tokens-from-a-solidity-smart-contract/ . The relevant contract is the DEX contract where you can see how it sends tokens.